# How can i combine Text and Images in a TextView at runtime

Tags: android, android-imageview, textview, spannablestring

Currently i have an application which displays pages of text in a `TextView` with the help of `ViewPager` and `Fragments`.

Is it possible to include images with the text in the text view which would be executed at runtime?

My initial idea was to use `SpannableString` and `ImageSpan`, but if the image is larger than one line of text will the rest of the text wrap around it or over pass it?

Can an `ImageView` be created at runtime put in a specific position and the text wraps around it?

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. Can you create a screen shot/image of what you want to have?

Comment: I want each page to be able to have both text and images, these pages should look something like a book's page with images. The catch is i want it to be set at run-time, i can't preset the image views from the XML files as there might be no images in one page and an image in another and have different positions.

Answer (score 0):

I did spannable for showing image in textview

```
public static Spannable getSmiledText(Context context, String text) {
    SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
    int index;
    for (index = 0; index < builder.length(); index++) {
        for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : emoticons.entrySet()) {
            int length = entry.getKey().length();
            if (index + length > builder.length())
                continue;
            if (builder.subSequence(index, index + length).toString().equals(entry.getKey())) {
                builder.setSpan(new ImageSpan(context, entry.getValue()), index, index + length,
                        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                index += length - 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return builder;
}

public static final HashMap<String, Integer> emoticons = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
static {
    // emoticons.put("cup:", R.drawable.cup);
    emoticons.put("glass", R.drawable.glasses);
    emoticons.put("bike", R.drawable.bike);
    emoticons.put("bottle", R.drawable.bottle);

}
```

then set text as

```
textView.setText(getSmiledText(context,"I love to ride bike with glass."));
```

It directly set image of bike(R.drawable.bike) and glasses(R.drawable.glasses) on TextView

Comment: Can the image be extended to more than one line, with the text still wrapping around it?

Comment: you can use \n for the nextline i.e "I love to ride \n bike with glass."